# JavaScript Math Function

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Given an object containing the number of positive and negative reviews, for example { positive: 24, negative: 8 }, return the review positivity score.

```
function getReviewPositivityScore (positive, negative) {
  let a = positive;
  let b = negative;
  let result = a - b  ;
  return  result;
}

module.exports = getReviewPositivityScore;
```

Error message I get:
getReviewPositivityScore
1) should return the number of positive reviews minus the number of negative reviews

0 passing (6ms)
1 failing

1. getReviewPositivityScore
   should return the number of positive reviews minus the number of negative reviews:

   AssertionError: expected NaN to deeply equal 16

   - expected - actual

   -NaN
   +16

   at Context. (.guides/secure/test3.5.1.js:8:17)
   at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:439:21)

Comment: Did you check the function input? It seems like positive was not a number

Comment: The input is an object, not two numeric arguments.

Comment: I know it's an obj but i didn't know how to put a single obj in to a math problem that has two numbers. That is why I wrote it as I did.

Comment: `function getReviewPositivityScore (obj) {
  let a = obj.positive;
  let b = obj.negative;`

Answer (score 1):

Since you are passing an object you only need one parameter as function input, and then access the values from it:

```
function getReviewPositivityScore (object) {
   return object.positive - object.negative;
}
```